# Where do I find the funding information for each math PhD program?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, funding

I will be applying for math PhD, and was wondering if there is any way to find the amount of stipend I can get for each program (already checked each school's website, without avail). Are top 50 math PhD programs generally fully funded, that I shouldn't be worried about it too much?

Comment: What country? Is this US?

Comment: Yes, I should've clarified. It's US

Comment: This is likely to be closed as a shopping question, but the most complete source of information on departmental finding is the AMS web page: https://www.ams.org/find-graduate-programs

Comment: "fully funded" isn't a really well defined term.  In addition to a stipend and tuition waiver, you should pay attention to health insurance and the cost of housing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the US almost all doctoral students in math are eligible for either a TA or an RA position, but mostly TA. The universities require a large number of TAs to manage the undergraduate program so as to free up professors for research and doctoral advising. Funding is modest, and 1/3 or so of your time might be spent on TA duties. Tuition is also normally waived for TAs.

Some professors might have funding for an RA or two, but there would still be duties.

But for those wishing a career in academia, starting out as a TA gives you some experience on the teaching side, if only (initially) grading and holding small tutorial sessions. An RA would be more valuable for someone wanting to go into industry, but they are not as common, and likely much more competitive.

There are relatively few positions that have no duties attached. At one time there were widely available federal scholarships under the [National Defense Education Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Defense_Education_Act) but those ended long ago. A few, more tailored, programs remain.

Comment: FYI, the NSF Graduate Research Fellowships still exist: https://www.nsfgrfp.org/ They are hard to get and underfunded, but sill around

Answer (score 2):

I'm a math PhD student in the US.  Programs in the US are almost always fully funded (including tuition & fees waived) for at least four or five years.  That being said, the *amount* of the yearly stipend can fluctuate wildly from school to school (especially when you account for different costs of living in different cities), and there's no way to get an actual number until you've been accepted to the program and received an offer.  It's also worth noting that the amount of the stipend is not necessarily correlated with the prestige of the university or department.

Comment: *there's no way to get an actual number until you've been accepted to the program and received an offer.*  This is sometimes true.  Most programs will tell you, at least roughly, what their stipend is if you write to them and ask.  And a few publish this information on their web pages.